# Mysql Coalesce treats field differently than where

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a strange condition in Mysql coalesce function:

```
select start_date, end_date, COALESCE(end_date, start_date) 
from log where log_id = 8999134
```

returns: 2011-02-09 23:00:38, NULL, NULL

Anyone has any idea why coalsce is not working as it should ?

**Edit**:

After some research I decided to try the query in MYSQL workbench and saw that the tool I was using to access the database was incorrectly returning null when the field had end_date = 0000-00-00 00:00:00. 
Yet the problem got even more strange. The result above is already a debug. The first query was:

```
select id, start_date, COALESCE(end_date, start_date) 
from log where end_date is null
```

from where I debugged:

```
 select id, start_date, end_date, end_date is null 
 from log where end_date is null
```

and the result was: 2011-02-09 23:00:38, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0

This is result's first line, but got equal results to the other lines. Why the end_date is NULL for where and not to coalesce ?

the datatype for both fields is datetime

Comment: If your tool is mucking around with `NULL` values, then one might suspect that it also mucks around with `is null`.

Comment: no because I tested it in SQL Workbench and the result was the same

Comment: That last query is a real problem.  If you are selecting where `end_date is null` in the `where` clause, then that value has to be true in the `select`.  If all you say is true exactly as you have written this, it could be a bug in MySQL.  That said, this seems unlikely given the many applications and people who use the software.

Answer (score 3):

This would occur if the value `NULL` were really a string `'NULL'`.  This would suggest that fields that should be *dates* are really being stored as *strings*.

Check the data types.  If they are `varchar()` or `char()`, then this is probably the problem.  Then, fix the problem by fixing the data structure.  Date/times should be stored using native database formats.

EDIT:

A date value of `0` is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: The datatypes of both fields is datetime. See my edit.

Comment: about your edit: then why where clause treats 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as NULL ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira . . . I see no evidence that is the case.  In fact, `end_date is null` is returning `0`, which is "false".

Comment: as I told in the other answer to @echo_Me: chech my post. what started this problem was that I used the condition "where end_date is NULL" to get that results. And where end_date is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' mysql is returing the line as if end_date was null

Comment: Still as you said end_date is null is returning 0. But the line is still included if I use it in "where end_date is null"

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira . . . Can you replicate this on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Actually no. The results are diffent in it and my server. link to my test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9b4a6/4/0

Comment: In my server line 3 would also be returned

Comment: It's not a sql_mode related problem because I checked SQLFiddle sql_mode and set my server accordingly.

Comment: My server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira . . . can you check if `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode is set?  I don't think it would have this effect, but it conceivably could.

Comment: There were no modes set when I first posted. Then I tried STRICT_TRANS_TABLES in order to be consistent with SQL Fiddle. but removed it after the test.

Answer (score 1):

if you have your dates stored like that 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then Coalesce will not work because its not NULL . try this with CASE :

```
    select id, start_date, CASE WHEN end_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
                                THEN start_date
                                ELSE end_date END as coalesced_date 
    from log where log_id = 8999134
```

Or this:

```
SELECT id, start_date, 
CASE WHEN end_date ='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND start_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
         THEN start_date
     WHEN start_date ='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND end_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
          THEN end_date
     WHEN start_date ='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND end_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
          THEN 'They are nulled'
     ELSE end_date END as coalesced_date 
FROM log 
WHERE log_id = 8999134
```

EDIT2:

you dont need to use NULL in your where clause since you dont have null values , you have `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` and this is not null.

so instead of

```
  where end_date is null
```

use

```
  where end_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: OK.. actually I had alredy used same idea only using if instead: IF(end_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', start_date, end_date). But the question remains: why where clause treats 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as NULL ?

Comment: never 0000-00-00 00:00:00 are treated as null, what you mean ?

Comment: chech my post. what started this problem was thet I used the condition "where end_date is NULL" to get that results. And where end_date is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' mysql is returing the line as if end_date was null.

Comment: Null dates are usually more work. but they much MUCH MUCH faster than zero dates for queries

Comment: my seggest transform your zero dates to null and use coalesce and null condition and all will be faster and eaiser.